# SetText from onActivityResult in Adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data from an Activity to other, so I use startActivityForResult and then get this data in onActivityResult.

The problem is that I don't know how to SetText with this data because I can't acces to TextViews (because they are in the ViewHolder) from the method onActivityResult in Adapter.

How to access to the TextView ? I would be very grateful for your help :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("newText", newText);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();
```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("newText");
/* Here I can't do : holder.textView.setText(result); */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to show the text in all view holders of the adapter or one?

Comment: only one viewHolder

Comment: Can you show me the code of the adapter class?

Comment: You don't need it, it's a classical Adapter

Comment: So what you have to do is to pass an additional int variable that represents the position of the view holder and using this position you will get the view holder. myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);

Answer (score 0):

You can declare textView as a global object.

Comment: Another option is to declare it as a static object in MainActivity or so.